# dynamically make pages and transit through them

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a page dynamically in android using eclipse... 
I have all the data required to make a layout etc in my database. All I want to do is to construct that page. My page contains various no. of buttons. On click of that button, I have to navigate to other page.
But, the other page should also be dynamically constructed as stored in the database.

What approach should I keep? 
What are the things to required to make a dynamic class?

EG:
Screen 1 has 3 buttons: 
btn1, btn2, btn3. 
On click of btn1, I check the database, and need to construct a class and then using the `Intent` object, transit through the class.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I created a skeleton table layout in the XML and added buttons in the table Layout according to the number of buttons to be displayed at run-time.